# Need PL/SQL script ideas

Tags: sql, date

I have extract the data from a set of tables which needs to have a where clause with the data as the column .
My team is making mistake in manually entering the date everytime they run the query . I want to write a PL SQL to take the date field dynamically from the database(oracle).
The following is  the query .

```
select oli.cart_key,lext.minor_order_number,wlkp.mf_wh_loc_id,oli.warehouse_type from tab1 oli,tab2 lext,tab3 wlkp where 
oli.cart_line_key = lext.cart_line_key and
oli.warehouse_code = wlkp.warehouse_code and
oli.warehouse_type = 'DC' and
lext.fulfillment_partner_key = 106 and
lext.order_status_secondary = 2000 and
lext.date_sent_to_fp is not null and
to_char(lext.date_sent_to_fp ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= ('01-APR-2014 03:00:00') and 
oli.active_flag = 'Y' and wlkp.active_flag = 'Y'
order by wlkp.mf_wh_loc_id
```

The date field '01-APR-2014 03:00:00' is something i want to get from the dual table. Is it possible to do the same ?

Please let me know .

Regards,
Arun

Comment: You need to clarify here.  You say you want a parameter, then you say it should come from the dual table.  The dual table has no date field so presumably you want the former?  Or do you want to use a parameter table with the date field in it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Frank. I want the date and time at 3 AM to come from the system/database is dd-MON-YYYY 03:00:00.As the query is run manually at 3 AM everyday

Answer (score 1):

Please do compare date as date types. You do not want base your comparation on the alphabet (DEC < NOV). Not only is it quite simpler but you will also save a call to the to_char function in every record (1 millon records, 1 millon calls !!).

```
select oli.cart_key,
       lext.minor_order_number,
       wlkp.mf_wh_loc_id,
       oli.warehouse_type 
  from tab1 oli,
  join tab2 lext on oli.cart_line_key = lext.cart_line_key 
  join tab3 wlkp ON oli.warehouse_code = wlkp.warehouse_code 
 where oli.warehouse_type = 'DC' 
   and lext.fulfillment_partner_key = 106 
   and lext.order_status_secondary = 2000 
   and lext.date_sent_to_fp is not null 
   and lext.date_sent_to_fp >= Trunc(SYSDATE) +3/24
   and oli.active_flag = 'Y' 
   and wlkp.active_flag = 'Y'
order by wlkp.mf_wh_loc_id
```

**Update**: If you run your query at the 1st of April at 3AM and your database is in the same timezone you do not need to do anything. Sysdate will take the vale of that date at 3 A.M.

But if you wanted to change the value to 3.AM of today just change "SYSDATE" with "Trunc(SYSDATE) +3/24" remove the time information from a new timestamp and add 3 hours.

Notes:

1. I changed your query to use the JOIN SYNTAX. It is clearer and
   sometimes it will improve performance.
2. You do not need the dual table. You already have a table to make the
   select.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion borjab. My only constraint is that the time field should be always at 03 AM . that is dd-MON-YYYY 03:00:00

Comment: Of Current date? But you said that this query is to be executed at 3.AM. Isn't it?

Comment: Of current date at 3 AM say today is 2nd April . Then the wher clause should contain ('02-APR-2014 03:00:00') , tomorrow it should become ('03-APR-2014 03:00:00')

Comment: In that case the updated version should work. You can test the date calculation with "SELECT Trunc(SYSDATE) +3/24 FROM dual".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the current date, you can use SYSDATE

```
select oli.cart_key,lext.minor_order_number,wlkp.mf_wh_loc_id,oli.warehouse_type from 
tab1 oli,tab2 lext,tab3 wlkp 
where 
oli.cart_line_key = lext.cart_line_key and
oli.warehouse_code = wlkp.warehouse_code and
oli.warehouse_type = 'DC' and
lext.fulfillment_partner_key = 106 and
lext.order_status_secondary = 2000 and
lext.date_sent_to_fp is not null and
to_char(lext.date_sent_to_fp ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') >= 
(SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL) and 
oli.active_flag = 'Y' and wlkp.active_flag = 'Y'
order by wlkp.mf_wh_loc_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion madhivanan. My only constraint is that the time field should be always at 03 AM . that is dd-MON-YYYY 03:00:00.

Comment: Then use SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY 03:00:00') FROM DUAL

Comment: It says date format not recognised, when i run this modified query